# How to calculate the area of the intersection of infinite union and finite set?

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

A line segment in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined as $\mathbb{L} = Conv\{\textbf{p}_1,\textbf{p}_2\}$. Obviously, its area is 0. Given a time-parameterized continuous trajectory $\textbf{T}(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2 \times SO1$, which contains position trajectory $\textbf{P}(t)$ and attitude trajectory $\psi(t)$. $\mathbb{L} (t) = \textbf{P}(t) + \psi(t)\mathbb{L}$. Define a circle $\textbf{C} = \{ \textbf{p} \ | \  ||\textbf{p} - \textbf{o}||^2  \leq r , \textbf{p}, \textbf{o} \in \mathbb{R}^2 \}$. How to calculate the area of the following set:
$$ \{  (\cup \mathbb{L} (t) \ | \ t \in [t_{a} , t_{b}] ) \cap \textbf{C} \}$$

Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUsfj.png) figure. The green line segment $\mathbb{L}$ move along a trajectory and the orange part is the target set.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.